# Do the onclick event of an button can call my python code?

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi

i have an html file with submit, reset and search button. I want that whenever i click search button it should call the python scipt to where there are some pythone search code.

I am not getting to what should i write in my html code so that i can call this python scipt on onclick event of search ??

Comment: anyones help is appreciated.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute Python script in web-browser.
Browsers can display HTML+CSS and execute JS scripts, nothing else.

You can try to rewrite your Python code on JavaScript or you must to use web-server with Python Web Framework, e.g. [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29).

Also you can try to use some means for compile(translate) Python to JS, however for this way it is necessary to have the corresponding experience.

**UPD**

You can't execute python script with CGI. You are needed Python Web Framework.